# Rails5 not precompiling assets on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Simple Rails 5.2 app with NO assets folder in `/public` (and therefor no manifest file)

When deploying, Heroku does no precompile the assets, it does not run the `rails assets:precompile` command at all.

I thought Heroku only skipped this if there was a manifest/digest file in the assets folder.

What am I missing?

Note: `config.public_file_server.enabled: true` is set

Answer (score 1):

In `config/production.rb` file

make this line:

`config.public_file_server.enabled: true`

It's supposed to serve public files.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a line of code in a rake reset task:
`exit(0) unless defined?(FactoryBot)`

Forgot rake tasks are also evaluated on system boot.

My Bad :(